# Upload file using AWS S3 return empty string in Flutter

Tags: ios, amazon-s3, flutter

I'm trying to do image upload with dart/flutter with aws s3 bucket using [flutter_amazon_s3](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_amazon_s3#-readme-tab-) and [amazon_s3_cognito](https://pub.dev/packages/amazon_s3_cognito) plugin. Image uploaded to aws s3 bucket successfully but in iOS Upload Image Url return empty string. It's working on Android, I'm new with aws s3.

Android Response

[image]

iOS Response

[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For IOS amazon_s3_cognito  plugin right now only works with buckets that have public access. Android version however is capable of uploading

Comment: Can you explain little why its not work with private access?

Answer (score 0):

To upload image to S3 bucket in flutter got success after using the below code, used flutter package - simple_s3

Package used : simple_s3: ^0.2.2

```
_uploadS3Image() async {
    //upload to S3 bucket
    String result = await SimpleS3.uploadFile(File(_capturedImage.path),
            bucketName, IDENTITY_POOL_ID, AWSRegions.usEast1,
            fileName: _capturedImage.path.trim().toLowerCase(),
            debugLog: true,
            accessControl: S3AccessControl.bucketOwnerFullControl)
        .catchError((error) {
      print("upload got error - ${error}");
    });
    print("uploadS3Image to S3 bucket response - ${result}");
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can upload image from IOS on Amazon S3 by using following steps.

1. add `amazon_s3_cognito` plugin in `pubspec.yml` file.
2. Use `upload` function of `amazon_s3_cognito` plugin.
3. open xcode and search Globally `SwiftAmazonS3CognitoPlugin`.
4. if you provide support then open the `.swift` file
5. search `uploadImageForRegion` on that file go that method.
6. add change lines according to code below.

   ```
   let arguments = call.arguments as? NSDictionary
   let imagePath = arguments!["filePath"] as? String
   let bucket = arguments!["bucket"] as? String
   let identity = arguments!["identity"] as? String
   let fileName = arguments!["imageName"] as? String
   let region = arguments!["region"] as? String
   let subRegion = arguments!["subRegion"] as? String
   ```
7. change the below lines after `uploadRequest`

   ```
   uploadRequest?.bucket = bucket
   uploadRequest?.key = fileName
   uploadRequest?.body = fileUrl as URL
   ```